# hide or remove the path in REST web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, curl, httprequest

how to hide or remove the project path in REST web service using java?
Now , I run my web service using curl command
 curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/bucket

But in CDMI standard (SNIA), they just request like
             PUT /user/bucket

I wonder how do they request or hide or remove the project path "/project/resources".
I just want to request SNIA without giving /project/resources
If anyone knows, please give some info .
thanks

Comment: All depends on what tools you use to build your service and how you deploy it.

Comment: hi bmargulies, i created it on NetBean Project and Jersey Framework. Do you know how to do?

Comment: Not so much. Changing the web.xml to map the servlet to /*, naming the webapp 'project', and then making the REST path /resources should do it, but I have never worked with those tools.

Comment: hi bmargulies, do u know where can i find the application.wadl file in netbean project?

Comment: Those are generated on the fly in CXF. Can't help you with this stuff.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any more sense today than when you asked exactly the same one the other day.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to configure a root resource 'user'. The Jersey documentation has an example of configuring a root resource here:
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#d4e53

Specifically notice the 'Path' annotation '@Path("/helloworld")'. I would guess that your root user resource path is set to /project/resources/user. This may be in the classes that Netbeans generated for you.

Comment: hi gred gianforcaro, where can i find the application.wadl in netbean project

Comment: Going off of the same documentation: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1843

The WADL is generated at runtime.

Comment: I think your wadl should be reachable at: http://localhost:8080/project/resources/application.wadl

Answer (score 0):

In their application server they are mapping the `/` path to the application serving the requests. Sounds like your app server is configured to map `/project/resources` to the application.

Comment: hi matt b,where can I find the application.wadl in netbean project?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with a `wadl` file and everything to do with how the server running your application is configured to map URL paths to it